# SwiftUI Intermittent Crash in iOS 16.3.1 and above

Tags: swiftui, crash, exc-bad-access

I'm working on a SwiftUI app, in profile tab it has a logout button. Intermittent crash would happen when clicking on this logout button on iOS version 16.3.1 or 16.4.1, but no crash on iOS 15 and iOS 16.1.1.

Below is the crash log on main thread, appreciate for any feedback on how to resolve this crash.

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000010
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000000010
VM Region Info: 0x10 is not in any region.  Bytes before following region: 68719476720
      REGION TYPE                 START - END      [ VSIZE] PRT/MAX SHRMOD  REGION DETAIL
      UNUSED SPACE AT START
--->  
      commpage (reserved)     1000000000-7000000000 [384.0G] ---/--- SM=NUL  ...(unallocated)

Termination Reason: SIGNAL 11 Segmentation fault: 11
Terminating Process: exc handler [1481]

Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:   Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                        0x1ba38e820 objc_msgSend + 32
1   UIKitCore                              0x1c354f4a4 -[UIViewController dealloc] + 772
2   UIKitCore                              0x1c354d0cc -[UINavigationController dealloc] + 308
3   UIKitCore                              0x1c37d5bbc -[_UISplitViewControllerColumnContents .cxx_destruct] + 44
4   libobjc.A.dylib                        0x1ba38e0a4 object_cxxDestructFromClass(objc_object*, objc_class*) + 116
5   libobjc.A.dylib                        0x1ba392e00 objc_destructInstance + 80
6   libobjc.A.dylib                        0x1ba39c4fc _objc_rootDealloc + 80
7   CoreFoundation                         0x1c130b26c cow_cleanup + 168
8   CoreFoundation                         0x1c1343538 -[__NSDictionaryM dealloc] + 148
9   libobjc.A.dylib                        0x1ba38e0a4 object_cxxDestructFromClass(objc_object*, objc_class*) + 116
10  libobjc.A.dylib                        0x1ba392e00 objc_destructInstance + 80
11  libobjc.A.dylib                        0x1ba39c4fc _objc_rootDealloc + 80
12  libobjc.A.dylib                        0x1ba38e0a4 object_cxxDestructFromClass(objc_object*, objc_class*) + 116
13  libobjc.A.dylib                        0x1ba392e00 objc_destructInstance + 80
14  libobjc.A.dylib                        0x1ba39c4fc _objc_rootDealloc + 80
15  UIKitCore                              0x1c354f8d8 -[UIResponder dealloc] + 124
16  UIKitCore                              0x1c354f5dc -[UIViewController dealloc] + 1084
17  libobjc.A.dylib                        0x1ba38e1d4 AutoreleasePoolPage::releaseUntil(objc_object**) + 196
18  libobjc.A.dylib                        0x1ba391bdc objc_autoreleasePoolPop + 256
19  UIKitCore                              0x1c34ef444 -[_UIAfterCACommitBlock run] + 92
20  UIKitCore                              0x1c34ef364 -[_UIAfterCACommitQueue flush] + 168
21  UIKitCore                              0x1c34ef278 _runAfterCACommitDeferredBlocks + 496
22  UIKitCore                              0x1c338dee4 _cleanUpAfterCAFlushAndRunDeferredBlocks + 108
23  UIKitCore                              0x1c384c608 _UIApplicationFlushCATransaction + 72
24  UIKitCore                              0x1c399ce00 _UIUpdateSequenceRun + 84
25  UIKitCore                              0x1c4000944 schedulerStepScheduledMainSection + 144
26  UIKitCore                              0x1c3fffea0 runloopSourceCallback + 92
27  CoreFoundation                         0x1c13b4208 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 28
28  CoreFoundation                         0x1c13c0864 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 176
29  CoreFoundation                         0x1c13456c8 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 244
30  CoreFoundation                         0x1c135b1c4 __CFRunLoopRun + 828
31  CoreFoundation                         0x1c13604dc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 612
32  GraphicsServices                       0x1fc5c035c GSEventRunModal + 164
33  UIKitCore                              0x1c36ec37c -[UIApplication _run] + 888
34  UIKitCore                              0x1c36ebfe0 UIApplicationMain + 340
35  SwiftUI                                0x1c4d2e3d8 0x1c4b72000 + 1819608
36  SwiftUI                                0x1c4c949b0 0x1c4b72000 + 1190320
37  SwiftUI                                0x1c4c7ea54 0x1c4b72000 + 1100372
38  MyApp                                  0x102f29b48 static MyApp.$main() + 40
39  MyApp                                  0x102f29bf0 main + 12
40  dyld                                   0x1e07e8dec start + 2220
```

Comment: [Here is a start from SwiftLee](https://www.avanderlee.com/swift/exc-bad-access-crash/)

Comment: i have the similar problem, have you found the root cause?

Comment: @LiangWang the issue is gone after NavigationView is moved to a higher level View. But root cause not clear yet.

Answer (score 1):

I just added `.animation(.default, value: repository.state)` in the `ContentView` where I am switching views based on user state i.e. user being signed in / out and didn't get crashes anymore.